# Why does fontspec interact with the footnote marks of the \thanks command?

Tags: symbols, fontspec

I have discovered a behavior that I cannot explain. When compiling the MWE

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\title{foo\thanks{bar}}
\author{baz\thanks{qux}}
\setlength{\textheight}{2.25in} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, the result is as expected:

[image]

Corresponding file list:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 ***********
```

However, uncommenting `\usepackage{fontspec}` and compiling with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX results in

[image]

Corresponding file list:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2015/02/13 v5524 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2015/02/13 v5524 L3 programming layer 
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3unicode-data.def    2015/02/12 v5523 L3 Unicode data
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
  xparse.sty    2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fontspec-xetex.sty    2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2014/07/25 v4.03 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

fontspec.cfg
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
 ***********
```

As you can see, only one distinct footnote mark is used when `fontspec` is loaded. This happens even if I load a system font using `\setmainfont` and/or friends. I use vanilla TeX Live 2014 (updated today) on Windows 7.

Is there a reason for this behavior or a problem with my setup? Or is this a bug that should be reported?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `fontspec-patches.sty` redefines `\@fnsymbol` as a protected function, while it should be fully expandable:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:cpn {@fnsymbol} #1 % NOT \cs_set_protected:cpn !!!
 {
  \int_case:nnF {#1}
   {
    {0} {}
    {1} { \mode_if_math:TF *\textasteriskcentered }
    {2} { \mode_if_math:TF \dagger\textdagger }
    {3} { \mode_if_math:TF \ddagger\textdaggerdbl }
    {4} { \mode_if_math:TF \mathsection\textsection }
    {5} { \mode_if_math:TF \mathparagraph\textparagraph }
    {6} { \mode_if_math:TF \|\textbardbl }
    {7} { \mode_if_math:TF {**}{\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered} }
    {8} { \mode_if_math:TF {\dagger\dagger}{\textdagger\textdagger} }
    {9} { \mode_if_math:TF {\ddagger\ddagger}{\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl} }
   }
   { \@ctrerr }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\textheight}{2.25in} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\title{foo\thanks{bar}}
\author{baz\thanks{qux}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

The protection should be at the level of the *values*, not at the main function's.

Comment: Indeed, I reported this to Will some time ago!

Comment: @JosephWright Fixing this bug warrants issuing a new version of `fontspec`.

Comment: Indeed! @JosephWright did you report this over "official channels" or should I do so? (Might help expedite a fix and all that.)

Comment: @PaulGessler Was just an e-mail to Will, I think: probably should get logged in the GitHub database

Comment: @JosephWright, ok, thanks for the info. Issue logged at GitHub [here](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/195).