# Titlingpage thanks footnote symbols show last symbol only (memoir class)

Tags: symbols, footnotes, memoir

I have a question regaring the `titlingpage` environment of the `memoir` class. I use `\thanks` multiple times on the title page, but the footnote symbol marks are all the same (the last symbol, which in my case is the last of the asterisk-dagger-ddagger ... set).

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

You van view both my entire code and compile the document here:
[EDIT: removed url, as it doesn't exist anymore]

I tried making a MWE, but couldn't reproduce it. The code is not very extensive yet, so I believe it is an incompatibility of `memoir` with a package or package setting.

Comment: I see you're using `fontspec`, so this seems to be the same problem as [Why does fontspec interact with the footnote marks of the `\thanks` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231258/). If it isn't, please provide a *minimal* document showing the issue.

Comment: @egreg I now have a different problem with the same not-so-minimal working example (the ShareLaTeX link). The font doesn't change according to my font selection in the Misc/Fonts.tex file. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Difficult to say, sorry: a MWE is needed.

Comment: @egreg I've minimised the example. Now it only uses the `fontspec` package (in Misc/Packages.tex). The DejaVuSansMono package should set the `tt` family font. Misc/Fonts.tex sets the main and sans serif fonts. All other unnecessary document files and settings have been removed. The font still doesn't change properly. And should I use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and why and in what order in Misc/Packages.tex?

Comment: Sorry again: a MWE should be a single file from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: I fixed it when I realised I had both a folder called Fonts and file Fonts.tex and I used `\input{Fonts}` somewhere else... This did not refer to the Fonts.tex file, so its contents weren't processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to egreg in the first comment on my question, I fixed the code in the link I posted in my question. I implemented the code fixing the problem in Misc/Packages.tex.